# Let $a,b,c$ be the side lengths...find $\frac{\tan C}{\tan A}+\frac{\tan C}{\tan B}$.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Let $a,b,c$ be the side lengths of an acute triangle $\triangle ABC$, respectively. If $\frac{b}{a}+\frac{a}{b}=6 \cos C$, determine $$\frac{\tan C}{\tan A}+\frac{\tan C}{\tan B}.$$

Comment: Please show your efforts in your post, using MathJax.

Answer (score 3):

First,${a\over b}+{b\over a}=6\cos C $ is equal to $a^2+b^2=6ab\cos C$.

So $c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos C=4ab\cos C$.

So $\sin^2C=4\sin A\sin B\cos C$.

Thus $${\tan C \over \tan A}+{\tan C \over \tan B}=\tan C({{\tan A+\tan B}\over \tan A\tan B})={\sin C \over \cos C}*{{\sin A\cos B+\sin B\cos A}\over \sin A\sin B}={{\sin^2C}\over \sin A\sin B\cos C}=4$$

Answer (score 0):

Using the theorem of cosines we get
$$\frac{b}{a}+\frac{a}{b}=\frac{6(a^2+b^2-c^2)}{2ab}$$ from here we obtain
$$c^2=\frac{2}{3}(a^2+b^2)$$ so we get
$$ \cos(\gamma)=\frac{a^2+b^2}{2ab}$$
Now we use that $$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}\geq 2$$ so
$$\cos(\gamma)=\frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}\right)\geq \frac{1}{3}$$ since $$\cos(\gamma)\le 1$$ we get …?
With $$\cos(\gamma)$$ we get $$\sin(\gamma)$$

Comment: $\frac ba+\frac ab=\frac{b^2}{ab}+\frac{a^2}{ab}=\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab}\ne\frac{6(a^2+b^2)}{2ab}$

Comment: @Andrei I think it was meant to say $\frac{6(a^2+b^2-c^2)}{2ab}$, from which the given formula for $c^2$ follows.

Comment: Where have i written this?

Comment: First equation.

Comment: I'd double-check your first formula for $\cos\gamma$ too if I were you. (Of course, I'd also write $C$ instead of $\gamma$, but to each their own.)

Comment: Aha, but it is given that $$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}=6\cos(\gamma)$$

Comment: and from here we get$$a^2+b^2=3(a^2+b^2-c^2)$$ to obtain $$c^2$$

Comment: Yes, so the formula should have $a^2+b^2-c^2$, not $a^2+b^2$. Otherwise there is no $c$ in your formula, so no way to get it.

Comment: Ok, take a pencil to control my calculations,i don't know where do you get $$a^2-b^2$$?

Comment: Sorry, it was + there. See my edit to your post

Comment: it is the equation $$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}=\frac{6(a^2+b^2-c^2)}{2ab}$$ and from here we get $$c^2$$

Comment: you can cancel $$ab$$ and the $2$

Comment: Yes, but you were missing the "$-c^2$" part from it

Comment: I have got $$c^2=\frac{2}{3}(a^2+b^2)$$ in the second line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90100/discussion-between-andrei-and-dr-sonnhard-graubner).

Comment: I have no time for that senseless discussion, or you show me the mistake in my calculations.